# Strikethrough files in TeamExplorer window of Visual studio

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012

While committing my project some of the files (dll and pdb) are strikethrough.

Why they are strikethrough?

I don’t want these file to be checkin into TFS as they all are of no work, they are just a pdb and the files under the obj and bin folders.

[image]

What should I do to remove those strikethrough file from the VisaulStudio TeamExplorer window and not to check in those fiels?

This problem starts when i fire one git command "git rm -r --cached **obj**" to remove obj folder and not to checkin it to TFS.

Comment: try to use UNDO command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strike through means you have deleted the file, and that the next commit will delete it from the git repo (tip only).  Since the git rm command worked, it means you have earlier committed these file to your repo.

It seems you don't have a .gitignore file to exclude these files from your commits from the start.
When you start up a new git repo, you should always ensure you have a proper .gitignore file.  That file will include patterns to exclude all dlls and exes, and also all pdb, and lot of other stuff you don't want in your repo.

If you use the Team Explorer Home page, and start a new solution there, it will automatically include a common .gitignore file for you. If not, you can add it from the Team Explorer/Settings page, Git Settings.  (PS: Add the .gitattributes at the same time).

In your situation now, you must either clean your repo for binaries, - which you would do if it is large, or just commit the deletes and live with some dlls/pdbs in your history - which you do if it is small.